# Get Navigation Timing backward/forward compatible - Convert from epoch to HR time

Tags: javascript, timestamp, unix-timestamp, epoch, navigation-timing-api

Let's introduce by a note from [*www.w3.org*](https://www.w3.org/TR/user-timing-2/#convert-a-name-to-a-timestamp) including two important links to compare.

> The PerformanceTiming interface was defined in [[NAVIGATION-TIMING]](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/) and
>   is now considered obsolete. The use of names from the
>   PerformanceTiming interface is supported to remain backwards
>   compatible, but there are no plans to extend this functionality to
>   names in the PerformanceNavigationTiming interface defined in
>   [[NAVIGATION-TIMING-2]](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing-2/) (or other interfaces) in the future.

I have made a function to get a Navigation Time that should be both backward and forward compatible, because we are in the middle era of transforming to level 2. So this function to *get a time from an event name* works in Chrome but not Firefox:

```
function nav(eventName) {
  var lev1 = performance.timing; //deprecated unix epoch time in ms since 1970
  var lev2 = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0]; //ms since page started to load. (since performance.timing.navigationStart)
  var nav = lev2 || lev1; //if lev2 is undefined then use lev1
  return nav[eventName]
}
```

Explanation: When there is no "navigation" entry this falls back to the deprecated way to do navigation timing based on *[Unix epoch time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp) time in milliseconds since 1970* (lev1), while the new way (lev2) is *[HR time](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time-2/#dom-domhighrestimestamp) in milliseconds since the current document navigation started to load*, that is useful together with User Timing that always have had the HR time format.

**How can we get the function return HR time in all cases?**

When I see a number with more than 10 digits without a period I know it is a time got from the deprecated Navigation Timing level 1. All other test cases give decimal point numbers meaning it is HR times with higher precision. The biggest issue is that they have *different [time origin](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time-2/#sec-time-origin)*.

I have gone through confusion, trial errors and frustrated serching (MDN has not updated to level 2) to confirm and state that:

- **Navigation** Timing Level 1 use [***unix epoch time***](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#terminology) and the rest...
- **Navigation** Timing Level 2 use *HR time*
- **User** Timing Level 1 use *HR time*
- **User** Timing Level 2 use *HR time*
- Also `performance.now()` has *HR time* both in Chrome and Firefox.

**How to convert [*unix epoch time*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp) to [*HR time*](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time-2/#dom-domhighrestimestamp)?**

---

**SOLVED .:**

*The code is corrected by help from Amadan.

See comments in tha accepted answer.*

```
function nav(eventName, fallback) {
  var lev1 = performance.timing; //deprecated unix epoch time in ms since 1970
  var lev2 = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0]; //ms since page started to load
  var nav = lev2 || lev1; //if lev2 is undefined then use lev1
  if (!nav[eventName] && fallback) eventName = fallback

  // approximate t microseconds it takes to execute performance.now()
  var i = 10000, t = performance.now()
  while(--i) performance.now()
  t = (performance.now() - t)/10000 // < 10 microseconds

  var oldTime = new Date().getTime(), 
      newTime = performance.now(),
      timeOrigin = performance.timeOrigin? 
                   performance.timeOrigin: 
                   oldTime - newTime - t; // approximate

  return nav[eventName] - (lev2? 0: timeOrigin);
  // return nav[eventName] - (lev2? 0: lev1.navigationStart); //alternative?
}
```

The [`performance.timeOrigin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/timeOrigin) is reduced in the case where old timing *lev1* is used.
If browser does not have it then approximate timeOrigin by reducing [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) *the time since timeOrigin*, from [(new Date().getTime())](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) *the time since Unix Epoch* to result in ***the time to timeOrigin since Unix Epoch***. Apparently it is the definition though the link was a bit vague about it. I confirmed by testing and I trust the answer. Hopefully w3c have a better definition of timeOrigin than: *the high resolution timestamp of the start time of the performance measurement*.

The functions returned value represents the time elapsed since the time origin.

It may be insignificant in most cases, but the measured time `t` it took to execute `performance.now()` is removed to approximate simultaneous execution.

I measured `t` to almost 10 microseconds on my Raspberry Pi that was fairly stable with various loop sizes. But my Lenovo was not as precise rounding off decimals and getting shorter times on `t` when tested bigger loop sizes.

---

*An alternative solution is commented away in the last line of code*.
The deprecated [`performance.timing.navigationStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming/fetchStart):

> representing the moment, in miliseconds since the UNIX epoch, right
>   after the prompt for unload terminates on the previous document in the
>   same browsing context. If there is no previous document, this value
>   will be the same as PerformanceTiming.fetchStart

So, to check current document (ignoring any previous) then use the deprecated [performance.timing.fetchStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming/fetchStart):

> representing the moment, in miliseconds since the UNIX epoch, the
>   browser is ready to fetch the document using an HTTP request. This
>   moment is *before* the check to any application cache.

It is of course correct to use a deprecated property if it is the only one the browser understand. It is used when "navigation" is not defined in the `getEntriesByType` otherwise having [good browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/getEntriesByType#Browser_compatibility).

---

A quick check confirmed each other by this line just before `return`:

```
console.log(performance.timeOrigin + '\n' + lev1.navigationStart + '\n' + lev1.fetchStart)
```

With a result that looks like this in my Chrome

> 1560807558225.1611
>   1560807558225
>   1560807558241

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only possible if the browser supports HR time 2:

```
let unixTime = hrTime + performance.timeOrigin;

let hrTime = unixTime - performance.timeOrigin;
```

However, `performance` is generally used for time diffs, which do not care what the origin of absolute timestamps is.

For the browsers that do not support HR time 2, or those that "support" it half-heartedly, you can fake it this way:

```
const hrSyncPoint = performance.now();
const unixSyncPoint = new Date().getTime();
const timeOrigin = unixSyncPoint - hrSyncPoint;
```

It's not super-exact, but should be good enough for most purposes (on my system, `performance.timeOrigin - timeOrigin` is sub-millisecond).

Comment: IE does not have the timeOrigin: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/timeOrigin#Browser_Compatibility

Comment: IE has never been very good about complying with standards. What else is new?

Comment: But the fallback to performance.timing has very good support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/timing

Comment: On my system, the `performance.timing.navigationStart - performance.timeOrigin` has larger error than my fake one above. YMMV.

Comment: The fake one may be genious - because it is a diff between unix epoch time and hr time. And browser support is good enough for me: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Yeah. The slight issue is that `performance.now()` and `new Date().getTime()` do not execute actually simultaneously, so there's a bit of a thing there. If you really need better precision on that, you might measure it one way, then measure it the other way, then average them. Repeatedly, for better results. Still doesn't guarantee exact result but... that's the best I have.

Comment: It is insignificant I believe: But to know the execution time of the line `const unixSyncPoint = new Date().getTime()` abowe to reduce it from `unixSyncPoint` approximated done simultaneously. We can do that line in a loop 1000 times and divide the time it takes by 1000 to know the execution time of the line.